# How can I save an input value so I can retrieve it next time I run the code (Python)?

Tags: python, database, input, save

Is there an easy way for me to store user input data so next time I run the program, it considers the previous value assigned to a variable?

I want to create a program to add 1 absence every time I don't attend a class. However, I don't know how to store that data. Ex.: I added 1 absence, and next time I run the code and add another, I want the program to retrieve 2 and not 1.

```
absence = None
userinput = input("add absence:")
userinput = int(userinput)
if absence == None:
   absence = userinput
else:
   absence = absence+userinput
print(absence)
```

Comment: Save it to a `.json` file. Python has built-in modules for saving and loading in JSON data.

Comment: JSON, CSV, database, pickle -- there are a dozen ways to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting a feeling you dont want to set up and maintain a database for this, you could go with the approach of saving or persisting the data in a json or xml file to your local path (or a cloud location) and access it every time your code runs.